# Objectify session cache on transaction retries

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

On the subject of **Transactions and Caching** the Objectify (v4) documentation says:

> Starting a transaction creates a new Objectify instance with a fresh, empty session cache. Loads and saves will populate this new instance cache; because of this, entities modified will appear modified after being loaded again within the same transaction

Ordinaily, this is fine, but can anyone clarify what happens to this cache on a **transaction retry**?  Does each retry clear the session cache, or does the same cache span the retries until success?

By way of example, let's increment a value in a `Thing`:

```
Thing thing = new Thing();
thing.setValue(1);
ofy().put().entity(thing).now();

// sometime later...

ofy().transact(new VoidWork() {
    public void vrun() {
        Thing thing = ofy().load().key(Key.create(thing)).safe();
        int val = thing.getValue();
        thing.setValue(val+1);
        ofy().save().entity(thing);
    }
});
```

On the first execution, Objectify will create a fresh, empty session cache for this transaction context.  `thing` will be then be cached, with `val` equal to `1`.  Let's assume the commit generates a `ConcurrentModificationException`, because another thread is also writing an updated `thing`.  This will cause Objectify to retry...

So, my question is this:  will Objectify use the cached `thing` (with `val == 1`), or will it explicitly reload it?  If it's reloaded, it should have `val == 2` because the other thread causing our `ConcurrentModificationException` will have updated it.

Thanks in advance for any clarification!